# How can I sort a list of strings representing tuples?

Tags: python, string, list, sorting, tuples

I have a list of strings which represent tuples, like so:

```
['(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q4,0)']
```

Is there any way to sort it by accessing the numbers after each q, so that the list looks like this:

```
[ '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q4,0)']
```

It would be easy if these were integers, however I need to keep the string format as they are now...

Comment: Not a dupe.  Regardless of title, this isn't a list of tuples, it's a list of strings that need to be tuple-fied.  Having said that, @nanachan if you ask how to split a string list into a tuple list in python, then check out the the dupe link, you should get sorted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can sort based upon a key which you define:

```
def my_key(value):
    return int(value.strip('()').split(',')[0][1:])
```

Usage:

```
>>> values = ['(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q4,0)']
>>> values.sort(key=my_key)
['(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q4,0)']
```

Comment: Would `[1:]` make more sense, in the case of multiple digits?

Comment: Yes, it definitely would

Comment: Thank you, this is really helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can split the string at the first "," using [`partition`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition) then `strip` "(q" customize the sort using by supplying a "key" function

```
lst = ['(q12,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q4,0)']    
sorted(lst, key=lambda item: int(item.partition(',')[0].strip('(q')))
# '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q4,0)', '(q12,0)']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
lt = ['(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q4,0)']
lt.sort(key=lambda st : int(st[2]) )
print(lt)
```

> **result**

['(q0,0)', '(q1,0)', '(q2,0)', '(q3,0)', '(q4,0)']

```
#st = '(q2,0)'
#st[2] = '2'
#int(st[2]) = 2
```